# Blue Prism - Application Modeller: Unique Attributes for Web Scraping

Tags: html, screen-scraping

I am new to Blue Prism and Web scraping. I want to scrape a list of items under a header. The header won't change, but the items in the list will.

**Example:**

**Member Listing**
Charles Schwab
TD Ameritrade

***List changes***

**Member Listing**
Well Fargo
TD Ameritrade

So how do I ensure the attributes in the Application Modeller for the list will always be able to scrape the changing items in the list?

I note some attributes like
tag name = UI
path=/HTML/BODY(1)/SGX-HEADER(1)/HTML/BODY(1)/DIV(1)/MAIN(1)/DIV(1)/ARTICLE(1)/TEMPLATE-BASE(1)/DIV(1)/DIV(1)/SECTION(1)/DIV(1)/SGX-WIDGETS-WRAPPER(1)/WIDGET-RICH-TEXT(5)/UL(1)

What do these attributes mean? Thank you

Comment: You would enumerate the li within the ul. The issue would come if anything earlier in the path changed.

Comment: @QHarr: Thanks for the reply. What does the number in the bracket mean? Eg WIDGET-RICH-TEXT(5). I note in the HTML of the website, they have class name and  data-analytics-category. Isn't it better to have a path that reference the class name & data-analytics-category.?

Comment: It's the 5th WIDGET-RICH-TEXT child tag.

Comment: @ QHarr: What do u mean child tag? Must 1 WIDGET-RICH-TEXT tag be embedded in another for it to be a child? <WIDGET-RICH-TEXT class='A'>  <WIDGET-RICH-TEXT class='B'> </WIDGET-RICH-TEXT></WIDGET-RICH-TEXT>

Comment: It is the 5th within `SGX-WIDGETS-WRAPPER(1)`

Answer (score 0):

You can create the attribute to be dynamic and verify it exists before reading it from the application. Once your app modeller is set up it will look something like

```
path=/HTML/BODY(1)/SGX-HEADER(1)/HTML/BODY(1)/DIV(1)/MAIN(1)/DIV(1)/ARTICLE(1)/TEMPLATE-BASE(1)/DIV(1)/DIV(1)/SECTION(1)/DIV(1)/SGX-WIDGETS-WRAPPER(1)/WIDGET-RICH-TEXT(5)/UL(1)
```

with this field being set to dynamic. At run time you have a flow that looks like the below:

[image]

this is what the flow would look like, check it exists then make space in a collection and read the value at the element path that exists. the wait stage looks like this:

[image]

so the flow Is straight forward enough, dynamic variable to track the element existing, once it exists confirmed by wait stage then read the contents at that path value and repeat until there are no more elements that exist and output the collection as a result.